# How to use MoveGroupInterface within a node?

Tags: moveit, control, ros-humble

I am a ROS beginner trying to write an interface for a robot arm in c++ that uses moveit2 for inverse kinematics. What I want to do is have a node with a MoveGroupInterface handle that I can use to set pose goals for moveit whenever it receives a message from a subscribed topic. However, the moveit2 tutorials only explain how to use the MoveGroupInterface class within the main function of a program. A link to the tutorial I am referring to is below:
https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html

The constructor for MoveGroupInterface requires a shared pointer to a node, and I don't know how I would create and spin a node within another node, or even that is good practice. The API for MoveGroupInterface is below: https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/api/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#a1d1040090d7a0457384bacaef839237e

I am just confused on the best way to send commands to moveit within an already created node. I have posted my current code, and would just like some help on how/where to implement MoveGroupInterface in it.

```
class IKInterface : public rclcpp::Node{
  public:
    IKInterface() : Node("ik_interface"){
      subscription_ = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Pose>(
      "pose_goal", 10, std::bind(&IKInterface::topic_callback, this, _1));
    }

  private:

    rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Pose>::SharedPtr subscription_;
    void topic_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Pose &goal_pose) const{
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "x val: %.5f\ny val: %.5f\nz val: %.5f", goal_pose.position.x, goal_pose.position.y, goal_pose.position.z);

    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<IKInterface>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation examples are a very good starting point for beginners. Experimenting with the basics helps us understand the requirements to implement IK solving or other functionalities. We can build our own C++ ROS2/MoveIt2 classes to do such functionalities through inheritance or composition. The point you mentioned about having some of the objects requiring a shared pointer to a node passed at construction is the main challenge.

**I will share with you two working examples of solving Ik using a class as you want, which is a good practice when designing our code functionalities.** The code examples below make a class `IKInterface` and implement a method `sampleSolveIK` for solving the IK problem. This method gets the arm's current pose and adds 5.0 cm to the *Z* coordinate to make a new pose. Then, it solves IK to check if this new pose is reachable.

(1) Using inheritance of `rclcpp::Node` class:

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
#include <moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h>
#include <moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose.hpp>

class IKInterface : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    IKInterface()
        : Node("ik_interface_node"),
          robot_model_loader_(std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(this->get_name()), "robot_description"),
          robot_model_(robot_model_loader_.getModel()),
          robot_state_(std::make_shared<moveit::core::RobotState>(robot_model_)),
          planning_group_("panda_arm") // Change planning_group_ to match your robot
    {   
        joint_model_group_ = robot_model_->getJointModelGroup(planning_group_);
    }

    void sampleSolveIK()
    {
        moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group_interface(std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(this->get_name()), planning_group_);
        
        // get current pose, increase its z coordinate by 5 cm and solve IK to see if the new pose is reachable
        auto current_pose = move_group_interface.getCurrentPose();
        geometry_msgs::msg::Pose target_pose;
        target_pose.position.x = current_pose.pose.position.x;
        target_pose.position.y = current_pose.pose.position.y;
        target_pose.position.z = current_pose.pose.position.z + 0.05; // Fixed to directly modify the z coordinate
        
        bool found_ik = robot_state_->setFromIK(joint_model_group_, target_pose);
        if (found_ik)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "IK solution found.");
        }
        else
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "IK solution not found.");
        }
    }

private:
    robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader_;
    moveit::core::RobotModelPtr robot_model_;
    moveit::core::RobotStatePtr robot_state_;
    std::string planning_group_;
    const moveit::core::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    
    auto ik_interface = std::make_shared<IKInterface>();
    ik_interface->sampleSolveIK(); 

    rclcpp::spin(ik_interface);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

(2) Using composition (our class has a shared ptr to `rclcpp::Node` as a member variable)

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
#include <moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h>
#include <moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose.hpp>

class IKInterface
{
public:
    explicit IKInterface(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node)
        : node_(node),
          robot_model_loader_(node, "robot_description"),
          robot_model_(robot_model_loader_.getModel()),
          robot_state_(std::make_shared<moveit::core::RobotState>(robot_model_)),
          planning_group_("panda_arm") // Change planning_group_ to match your robot
    {
        joint_model_group_ = robot_model_->getJointModelGroup(planning_group_);
    }

    void sampleSolveIK()
    {
        moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group_interface(node_, planning_group_);
        
        // get current pose, increase its Z cordiate 5 cm and solve IK to see if the new pose is reachable
        auto current_pose = move_group_interface.getCurrentPose();
        geometry_msgs::msg::Pose target_pose;
        target_pose.position.x = current_pose.pose.position.x;
        target_pose.position.y = current_pose.pose.position.y;
        target_pose.position.z += current_pose.pose.position.z + 0.05;

        bool found_ik = robot_state_->setFromIK(joint_model_group_, target_pose);
        if (found_ik)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "IK solution found.");
        }
        else
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "IK solution not found.");
        }
    }

private:
    rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node_;
    robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader_;
    moveit::core::RobotModelPtr robot_model_;
    moveit::core::RobotStatePtr robot_state_;
    std::string planning_group_;
    const moveit::core::JointModelGroup *joint_model_group_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    
    auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("ik_interface_node");
    IKInterface ik_interface(node);
    ik_interface.sampleSolveIK();

    rclcpp::spin(node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested both examples with the `panda_arm` used in MoveIt demos and they work well and give the same result. Please change the planning group name to your robot's planning group when using it. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely helps.